# J2EE HttpServlet. Controller's actions not working

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, servlets, web-applications

I am following a tutorial book to develop a CRUD web application with J2EE and now it started using `HttServlet`. It might be that the book is not very new or that I don't really know how to do this.

I have my controller class, something like this:

```
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
        Action action = null;

        if (request.getServletPath().equals("/Insert.do")) {

            action = new InsertAction();

        } else if (request.getServletPath().equals("/Delete.do")) {

            action = new DeleteAction();

        .....

        } else {

            action = new FilterShowAction();

        }
        dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(action.execute(request, response));
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

The tutorial made me create a new different class for every different CRUD action, forms, and a couple more things.

Here's the `Action` class:

```
public abstract class Action {
    public abstract String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws UnsupportedEncodingException;
}
```

But then when I type `localhost:8080/myapp/Controller/SomeAction.do` I get an Error 404. Only when I type `localhost:8080/myapp/Controller` I get something else: the last else block in the `doGet` method is executed; anyway, I get a `NullPointerException`.

I have no idea how to do this thing right, and the book doesn't give any more information. I couldn't find a solution anywhere else.

Also, I don't understad what is the `.do` extension. The book just comes up with it and makes you include it in your code without explaining what the heck it is. I didn't find any information in the Internet either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Controller</display-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.Controller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>Controller</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
    <location>/Error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Comment: your web.xml defines all the paths(Including .do extension) for the applciation, please paste that file here.

Comment: Post your deployment descriptor.

Comment: I had no idea `web.xml` had anything to do with this matter. That must be it. What should I do?

Comment: Apparently you want to map *.do to your controller servlet. So that's the url-pattern to use, right now you've configured it so that you can only invoke the controller servlet by requesting /Controller. I don't know where you've copied the web.xml from but it must be ancient given that its servlet specification 2.3; you probably want to find a more updated resource to learn this stuff from.

Comment: @Gimby could you please tell me how to map my *.do to my controller servlet?

Comment: I'd rather take this as a hint that you need to research how to properly configure and work with servlets. Otherwise this is going to be a futile exercise of you asking what to do next each little step you take.

Comment: Thanks I already solved it.